# How to use :inverse_to in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

### :inverse_to doesn't work with my complex case

```
class Communication::Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation_for_proposal, {
    :class_name  => 'Communication::Conversation::ForProposal',
    :foreign_key => :conversation_id,
    :inverse_of  => :messages_for_proposal
  }
end

class Communication::Conversation::ForProposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages_for_proposal, {
    :class_name  => 'Communication::Message',
    :foreign_key => :conversation_id,
    :inverse_of  => :conversation_for_proposal
  }
end
```

**Problem: Communication::Conversation::ForProposal doesn't know about messages**

```
Communication::Conversation::ForProposal.new.messages_for_proposal.build.conversation_for_proposal # => ok

Communication::Message.new.build_conversation_for_proposal.messages_for_proposal # => []
```

Reflections:

```
Communication::Message.reflect_on_association(:conversation_for_proposal).active_record
# => Communication::Message

Communication::Message.reflect_on_association(:conversation_for_proposal).inverse_of.active_record
# => Communication::Conversation::ForProposal
```

What I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the :inverse_of option.

```
class Post < AR::Base
  has_many :comments, :inverse_of => :post
end

class Comment < AR::Base
  belongs_to :post, :inverse_of => :comments
end
```